# Spyder: typing an opening bracket in console puts focus on internal console

Tags: python, console, spyder

I have recently re-installed spyder on ubuntu 12.04. Here is the problem:
When I type an opening bracket in the console, the focus switches immediately to the internal console, displaying an error (that I interpret as "missing closing bracket"?) While I appreciate the code monitoring, it would be nice if the console let me finish my line of code first before jumping to conclusions.

How can I avoid this behavior? (I dont mind the "error" showing in the internal console, but the switch to the internal console whenever I open a bracket is quite disruptive.)

Here is the output of the internal console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/spyderlib/widgets/shell.py", line 298, in keyPressEvent
self.postprocess_keyevent(event)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/spyderlib/widgets/shell.py", line 727, in postprocess_keyevent
ShellBaseWidget.postprocess_keyevent(self, event)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/spyderlib/widgets/shell.py", line 438, in postprocess_keyevent
self._key_parenleft(text)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/spyderlib/widgets/shell.py", line 797, in _key_parenleft
self.show_object_info(last_obj, call=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/spyderlib/widgets/mixins.py", line 608, in show_object_info
signature=True, color='#2D62FF')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/spyderlib/widgets/mixins.py", line 108, in show_calltip
self.calltip_widget.show_tip(point, tiptext, wrapped_textlines)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/spyderlib/widgets/calltip.py", line 157, in show_tip
forward=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spyder-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/spyderlib/widgets/calltip.py", line 252, in _find_parenthesis
while category(char) != 'Cc' and position > 0:
TypeError: need a single Unicode character as parameter
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug that should be reported to spyder's developers...

Comment: @Freundchen, did you use the ubuntu package or installed another version of spyder? Can you give more information about your setup.

Comment: I installed the ubuntu package via apt-get. Sorry, I am not an expert - any more info I can provide?

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) Could you post an example that shows the error you're getting? or does this happen with *every* parenthesis you write in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not show errors on the *Internal console*, you need to go to

```
Tools > Preferences > General > Debugging
```

and deactivate the option called

```
[ ] Pop up internal console when internal errors appear
```

Comment: ...and I overlooked that the whole time... yay me! thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't forget to give us a simple example that reproduces your problem so we can fix it for everyone :)